# Is there any way to add the GIT JSON packet into HTTP POST request in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

How to get the JSON packet from Git and add it to the Jenkins HTTP POST request plugin

I'm trying to do the http POST call from Jenkins, but the request packet for the POST method is something I'm trying to fetch from GIT. I tried to use Groovy, but no luck. Using Groovy, I'm able to read the Git file, but I'm unable to add that file's content into the HTTP POST call. Is there any way to get the data from the file and add it to the HTTP request?